# Adding Corner radius for selected edges with shadow using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer, uibezierpath

I am trying to add a shadow on my view. It is having 3 rounded edges. To achieve this UIBezierPath and then setting the CAShapelayer with this path as the mask on the layer of the view. Now, if I'm trying to add shadow on this view, it is not showing. I have gone through a similar question and suggested answers but nothing works in my case. Following is my implementation:

```
class BubbleView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.updateContainerLayer()
}

func updateContainerLayer() {
    let brazierPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                                 byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft, .topLeft],
                                                 cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15.0, height: 0.0))

    //1
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = brazierPath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

    //2
    self.layer.shadowColor  = UIColor(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.5)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
    self.layer.shadowPath   = brazierPath.cgPath
    //3
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.clipsToBounds = false
    //4
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale


}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting **iOS 11+** you can use the layer's `.maskedCorners` property:

```
class BubbleView: UIView {

    // don't override draw()
//  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
//      super.draw(rect)
//  }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.updateContainerLayer()
    }

    func updateContainerLayer() {
        let brazierPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                                     byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft, .topLeft],
                                                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15.0, height: 0.0))

        //1
//      let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
//      shapeLayer.path = brazierPath.cgPath
//      self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

        // iOS 11+ use .maskedCorners
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]

        //2
        self.layer.shadowColor  = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.5)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        self.layer.shadowPath   = brazierPath.cgPath
        //3
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        //4
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale


    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Result with an exaggerated `.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -10.0, height: 10.5)` to make it easy to see the shadow:

[image]

If you need to allow earlier iOS versions, I *believe* you'll need to use a container view approach.

---

**EDIT:**

Another approach, using a "container" view for the shadow. This will work with iOS earlier than 11... it uses the same `UIBezierPath` for the "content view" mask and the shadow path:

class BubbleView: UIView {

```
let contentView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() -> Void {

    addSubview(contentView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        ])

    self.clipsToBounds = false

    backgroundColor = .clear
    contentView.backgroundColor = .red

    // set non-changing properties here
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.layer.shadowColor  = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0

    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.5)

    // exaggerated shadow offset so we can see it easily
    //self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -10.0, height: 10.5)

    self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5

    self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                  byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft, .topLeft],
                                  cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15.0, height: 0.0))

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    contentView.layer.mask = shapeLayer

    self.layer.shadowPath   = bezierPath.cgPath

}
```

}

As with the 11+ example, Result:

[image]

and Result with an exaggerated `.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -10.0, height: 10.5)` to make it easy to see the shadow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks For your solution. But I'm targetting iOS 10 as well. "container view approach." - can you please elaborate this.

Comment: thanks !! With a little tweak and your suggestion, finally, it is done !!